# dropna() trouble with labels

Tags: python, csv, pandas, average

I'm attempting to average a set of data in pandas. The data in from a csv file.
I have a series called 'track'. In earlier stages I have used the method `dropna()` to get rid of some blank rows that were imported when I read the csv file.

I use the method that I would like to average over 5 rows of the columns. I cannot use the rolling_mean method as I would like to take the average using the two rows before the current value, the current value and the two rows after the current value.

I hit problems when I get to data where the NaN data has been removed as the labels also go.

```
def get_data(filename):
    '''function to read the data form the input csv file to use in the analysis'''
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',', usecols=('candidate',' final track' ,' status'))                      
    print reader[0:20]            
    reader=reader.dropna()
    print reader[0:20]
    return reader 

def relative_track(nb):

    length= len(reader) 
    track=current_tracks.loc[:,' final track']
    for el in range(2, length):
        means=pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean(track, 5)
        print means
```

This gives the output (Note labels at 15, 16 are missing in second print):

```
                candidate   final track  status
0                       1           719       *
1                       2           705       *
2                       3           705       *
3                       4           706       *
4                       5           704       *
5                       1           708       *
6                       2           713       *
7                       3           720       *
8                       4           726       *
9                       5           729       *
10                      1           745       *
11                      2           743       *
12                      3           743       *
13                      4           733       *
14                      5           717       *
15                    NaN           NaN     NaN
16  *** Large track split           NaN     NaN
17                      1           714       *
18                      2           695       *
19                      3           690       *
   candidate   final track  status
0          1           719       *
1          2           705       *
2          3           705       *
3          4           706       *
4          5           704       *
5          1           708       *
6          2           713       *
7          3           720       *
8          4           726       *
9          5           729       *
10         1           745       *
11         2           743       *
12         3           743       *
13         4           733       *
14         5           717       *
17         1           714       *
18         2           695       *
19         3           690       *
20         4           671       *
21         5           657       *
```

but when I try to compute the means using the second function I get the error:

```
    raise KeyError("stop bound [%s] is not in the [%s]" % (key.stop,self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'stop bound [15] is not in the [index]'
```

This is because the index 15 is not there. If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot use the rolling_mean method as I would like to take the average using the two rows before the current value, the current value and the two rows after the current value.

Use the keyword argument `center=True`, described toward the end of [this section of the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments).

Also, `pd.stats.moments.rolling_mean` can be accessed simply as `pd.rolling_mean`; it is a top-level function in pandas.

P.S. I think I understood your intentions here, but your code may have some problems unrelated to your question. (For example, the `el` counting variable in the last for loop is not used -- it looks like it just does the same thing repeatedly.) But maybe the `center` keyword can obviate most of your existing work anyway.